# function to recursively remove outliers

Tags: r

I wrote a function to remove outliers resursively (for any data points 3sd away from its median.

```
rm.outlier <- function (var) {
    has.3sd =1
    while (has.3sd>0) {
        for (l in var) {
            if ( (l-median(var))> 3*sd(var) & !is.na(l)) {
                var[var==l] <- NA
            }
        }
        has.3sd <- sum(var > 3*sd(var))
        if (has.3sd==0) {
            break
        }
    }
    return (var)
}
```

However, I always got the error message:

> Error in if ((l - median(var)) > 3 * sd(var) & !is.na(l)) { : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I wonder why I got this error message? I spent long time trying to figure it out but couldn't. I appreciate it if anyone can help me with that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This most likely happens because you set the outliers to `NA`. After you have eliminated the first outlier, the functions `median(var)`, `sd(var)` and `sum(var > 3*sd(var))` return `NA` instead of the numeric value you expect it to return. You can fix this by adding the argument `na.rm = TRUE` to the functions mentioned above.

Comment: Just don't. Automatic removal of outliers is dubious at best, but at least there are tests available that can identify more than one outlier. However, recursively applying a 3SD rule around the median will give you bogus.

Comment: I agree with Roland. There are all sorts of reasons that this is not the right way to clean your data.

Comment: thanks everyone! I'm trying to remove some outliers for visualization purpose. There are some outliers in latitude and longitude. If not removed, my map is screwed.  ikop's solution works